# On the web, what fonts should I use to create an equivalent experience cross-platform?

Tags: css, linux, fonts, cross-platform

Because Linux (and its variants) have a completely different set of fonts than Windows and Mac OS X, is there anyone with any experience of creating cross-platform font families - ideally finding equivalents to the common fonts found on the aforementioned operating systems?

If so, what is the best route to take?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are some good up-to-date listings of the most-installed fonts for PC, Mac, and Linux:

[Sans serif font sampler and survey results](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-SansSerif.shtml)

[Serif font sampler and survey results](http://www.codestyle.org/css/font-family/sampler-Serif.shtml)

Hope this helps your decision!

Answer (score 5):

[List of Web Safe Fonts](http://www.fonttester.com/help/list_of_web_safe_fonts.html).

Comment: The tool here from that site is the definitive resource. It's easy to send a link to clients and let them choose.

http://www.fonttester.com/web_safe_fonts.html

Answer (score 4):

Most OS'es have support for Microsoft's [Core Fonts For the Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_fonts_for_the_Web). They all come bundled with OSX, and I'm reasonably sure they'll work (or have near-identical variants) on most any linux distro.

[The Microsoft Typography page is also pretty cool](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/default.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify: You are looking for names of fonts that will make your website-design look similar to Windows and Mac OS X when viewed under Linux, you are not looking to design new fonts, correct?

(I read your question in the same way that Jason Navarrete did, so at least two people misunderstood your question.)

The font names you are looking for might be something like [the Liberation fonts that RedHat has released](https://www.redhat.com/promo/fonts/)?

Incidently, 'sans-serif' doesn't give the user "any sans-serif", it gives the user his/her *preferred* sans-serif - which may arguably be better than one you pick.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is a hard question.

There are generally 3 fonts that are in some form or other always supported. These fonts are Adobe Times, Adobe Helvetica, and Adobe Courier. The problem is that while every system and foundry have a clone of these, they have different names. They are also not entirely the same, but have the same metrics. The windows trio: Arial, Times New Roman, and Courier New are the monotype clones of them. On linux these have been provided as bitmap fonts by adobe, and as outlines in form of the URW Nimbus {Sans, Roman, Mono} clones. The outlines however are not pretty on screen (they are on a printer) as they lack hinting.

The solution would be to go for a multichoice for websites. As microsoft has at some point made the ["core fonts"](http://corefonts.sourceforge.net/) available for redistribution, many unix/linux systems do have those fonts available. So go with them. The liberation fonts are straight clones of the MS/monotype fonts, so should go ok as alternatives with a similar experience. Then go for "Helvetica", "Times", and "Courier" before the sans/serif/mono choice that puts you in the user's hands.

Answer (score 3):

Sitepoint has an excellent article on font stacks:

http://www.sitepoint.com/article/eight-definitive-font-stacks/

Answer (score 2):

> TrueType Fonts (TTF) will generally work on Windows, Mac, and Linux platforms.

Thanks Jason, but this isn't the answer I'm looking for. Many Linux distributions come with their own fonts that are different *in name* to the Mac/Windows versions - presumably because of font licensing issues.

I'd like a response from a Linux user (preferably developer) who has experience with coming up with similar looking fonts. I really don't want to have to give Ubuntu Firefox users 'any sans-serif'.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://safalra.com/web-design/typography/web-safe-fonts-myth/) explains the basic approach that has the most chance of working cross-platform. You have to think in terms of stacks which are sets of broadly similar fonts which cover most platforms.

You are always safe saying 'serif' which will get you Times New Roman or similar or sans-serif which will get you Helvetica/Arial or similar on most platforms. Then as the article suggests you can go further and distinguish between 'wide' and 'narrow' groupings.

You can take a more 'progressive enhancement' approach choosing your ideal font and providing generic substitutes for those platforms which do not have it. However at the end of the day the web is not print and you only get approximate control over font choice. You can do a lot of custom typography using the well-supported CSS properties such as line-spacing. But you will never be able to say 'use this font' and have it work the identically even across Mac/Windows/Linux let alone mobile devices, kiosks etc...

Answer (score 0):

TrueType Fonts (TTF) will generally work on Windows, Mac, and Linux platforms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType