# What fonts support a large number of weights? / How to fake font-weight?

Tags: css, fonts

Specs:

- JS required amyway on site. but prefer pure-CSS/HTML
- IE7+, iPhone supported
- Old browsers (e.g. IE6) not supported
- Standard HTML with no crazy kludges (eg cufon, images, cifr).

Questions:

1. What fonts support 4 or more weights? Most seem to only have one or two. Answers so far:

   - Myriad Pro (supposedly? test below fails for me)
2. How can I degrade gracefully to some other styling that mimics the perceptual effect of font weight?

Relevant links:

- http://www.clagnut.com/blog/2228/ (1 yr old)
- http://clagnut.com/sandbox/fontweight.html (my OSX.6 Firefox & Safari show only two weights)
- http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340923/what-is-the-most-readable-appealing-font
- [All about choosing the right font for a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929537/all-about-choosing-the-right-font-for-a-website)
- [Font (typeface) selection for the Web?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410461/font-typeface-selection-for-the-web)
- [On the web, what fonts should I use to create an equivalent experience cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336/on-the-web-what-fonts-should-i-use-to-create-an-equivalent-experience-cross-plat)

Answer (score 5):

The first question is not what *fonts* support a large number of weights: It's whether the *browsers* do.

The answer, as far as I can see, is, no they don't, not reliably. `normal` and `bold` are the only two weights you can work with really.

See the related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438203/are-all-css-font-weight-propertys-values-useful). I think this 2009 Blog post still holds true:

[Font-weight is still broken in all but one browser](http://www.clagnut.com/blog/2228/)

**Update:** I overlooked that you already link to that particular post, sorry. I think it's still the state of the nation - at least, I doubt this is achievable for IE 7 without Cufon, sIFR and similar.

**Update 2:** See [Eric Meyer's test suite](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/tests/css2/sec15-02-03c.htm) for a live example to test on.