# list of safe fonts for MODERN browsers

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On the web, what fonts should I use to create an equivalent experience cross-platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336/on-the-web-what-fonts-should-i-use-to-create-an-equivalent-experience-cross-plat)

To handle some of the limitations of older browsers, I decided to make part of my web app only accessible on modern browsers (IE8+, chrome, firefox 4+, safari). I want to take advantage of these browsers' capabilities and use their ability to handle fonts beyond the traditional web-safe fonts.

Where can I find a list of fonts that safe to use in **MODERN browsers** so that in my CSS I can just type {font-family:xyz;} and it just works like intended.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't have to do as much with browsers, as it does with operating systems and the default fonts installed on them (plus other widespread sources of fonts like MS Office, graphics programs...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font selection has nothing do to with how modern the browser is. **Font selection is limited to what is installed by default on Windows/Mac OS X/Linux**.

However, with modern browsers, you have the option to [embed custom fonts using the CSS `@font-face` declaration](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/). If you decide to embed a font using CSS, **make sure that the font's license permits you to do so**. [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) & [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts/) have a large collection of embeddable fonts.

Comment: with font embedding in mind, the sky's the limit! http://dafont.com has some nice ones as well.

Comment: @Thomas: Font licenses on dafont.com are ambiguous at best. Avoid if you don't want trouble.

Comment: Oh, wasn't aware of that; thanks! I'll def. check out those you mentioned.